# Facebook messenger Webview - X-Frame-Options

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to give webview on button click from facebook messenger,
but it gives me error like,

```
messenger.Extensions.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
    at Object.reportError (messenger.Extensions.js:97)
    at Object.applyWithGuard (messenger.Extensions.js:97)
    at c (messenger.Extensions.js:158)
    at messenger.Extensions.js:78
```

**Get method**

```
app.get('/checkout', (req, res, next) => {
    let referer = req.get('Referer');
    if (referer) {
        if (referer.indexOf('messenger') >= 0) {
            res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com/');
        } else if (referer.indexOf('facebook') >= 0) {
            res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/');
        }
        res.render('checkout');
    }
});
```

***Messenger SDK Code***

```
 (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));
    window.extAsyncInit = () => {
        // TODO: How to parse env file from here?
        MessengerExtensions.getSupportedFeatures(function success(result) {
            let features = result.supported_features;
            console.log(result);
            if (features.includes("context")) {
                MessengerExtensions.getContext('<APPID>',
                    function success(thread_context) {
                        // success
                        document.getElementById("psid").value = thread_context.psid;
                    },
                    function error(err) {
                        // error
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                );
            }
        }, function error(err) {
            // error retrieving supported features
            console.log(err);
        });
        document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
            MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(function success() {
                console.log("Webview closing");
            }, function error(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    };
```

I want PSID when a user submits the form. Getting success when I submit a form from messenger app. but getting an error in the browser.

Comment: We are currently experiencing the same issue without any changes related to messenger, so I assume this is an issue on facebook's side.

Comment: THANKS, can you tell me where can I request facebook for this issue.

Comment: I have submitted an issue here, maybe you can also comment on there: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/262071487871777/

Comment: Sure,, @Birne94

Comment: Same issue for me. It was working perfectly last week.

Comment: @Baudev Its working Now

Comment: @Birne94 Its working Now